# Creating a hidden directory in a repository

Tags: git

I'm not sure my title is at all descriptive, so let me tell you the problem and even if you cannot solve it, maybe you can suggest a better title.

I have two programming teams.  The in-house team has access to all the source code, of course, but the outsourced team is supposed to have access to everything, except one directory way down in the tree.  There's proprietary stuff in there and those guys should not be able to see it, let alone change it.  Ideally, they won't even be aware of its existence.

Maybe I should have two remote repositories, one with the common files and one with the proprietary stuff, but in that case, how do the developers created a mixed repository, where the root of one branch tracks from one remote and a directory deeper down tracks from another?

I can't believe I'd be the first person with the problem but I cannot even think of a way to phrase it for a good Google search.

Comment: What would happen if the outsource team creates a directory with files with the same name and commits it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how it'd behave, but you might be able to put the other stuff in a different repository, and include it as a submodule; just don't give them access to the repository that is the submodule.

Comment: @WTP -- that's a legitimate problem in the general case, but in my case, the *parent* directory of the hidden directory is special-purpose, and the outsourcing team is not supposed to be creating *any* new directories there, let alone one that happens to have the same multi-character, non-obvious name.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to split your project into 2 different repositories and link them using a [submodule](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html).

This way you can just have a different set of permissions for each repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [gitignore](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) file to specify files/directories that GIT should not handle.

Comment: Yes, but I think he *wants* git to handle the files; he just doesn't want the external team to have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gitslave (http://gitslave.sf.net) or [git submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial) to form a tree with your public repo at the top and the hidden repo at the bottom.

gitslave would work better for you since it will not interfere with the normal git commands like git-submodules tends to do, meaning that the people without access to the submodule will not be annoyed/harmed by its absence.  gitslave also works better since you will presumably be doing active development on both trees and thus do not need to do the checkout/commit/commit dance that submodules requires.